# Python: how to change an attribute of a parent class via child class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Basically, I want to modify a base class attribute in one of its child classes, and afterwards keep the new value, so the rest of child classes inheriting from the parent class will have the new value:

```
class Parent(object):
    x = False

class Child1(Parent):
    x = True
```

Now if I have another child class and call its x attribute, I want it to be 'True' rather than 'False'. How do I do this?

Comment: That does not sound like best practice. What's your use-case / the problem you like to solve with it?

Comment: Children don't inherit the *value* of a parent class's attribute, they inherit the attribute itself. You want a factory function that takes a parameter whose value is used to set the new child's `x` attribute.

Comment: Put another way, inheritance shouldn't modify the thing being inherited from.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can see of doing this is using an intermediate class which all of the children class inherit.

```
class Parent(object):
    x = False
class Intermediate(Parent):
    x = True
class Child1(Intermediate):
    //...data
class Child2(Intermediate):
    //...data
```

Comment: Would it be possible if Child1 returns 'x = True' and I somehow incorporate the new 'x = True' to Child2 without inheritance?